# Conflict with two function

Tags: javascript, telerik-grid

I am trying to call a function with almost the same parameters but the 2nd function is not working when the 2nd button is press

Here's the code

```
; (function ($, undefined) {
    var grid;
    var demo = window.demo = {};
   
    Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
        grid = $telerik.findControl(document, "RadGrid2");
             
    });

    demo.ShowColumnHeaderMenu = function (event, columnName) {

        var columns = grid.get_masterTableView().get_columns();
        
        for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            if (columns[i].get_uniqueName() == columnName) {
                columns[i].showHeaderMenu(event, 75, 20);
            }
        }
    };


   
})($telerik.$);

; (function ($, undefined) {
    var grid1;
    var demo1 = {};
   
    Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
        grid1 = $telerik.findControl(document, "RadGrid1");

    });

    demo1.ShowColumnHeaderMenu = function (event, columnName) {

        var columns = grid1.get_masterTableView().get_columns();

        for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            if (columns[i].get_uniqueName() == columnName) {
                columns[i].showHeaderMenu(event, 75, 20);
            }
        }
    };



})($telerik.$);
```

the 1st button that calling the 1st function is working fine

```
<img src="Img/Menu.png" onclick='demo.ShowColumnHeaderMenu(event,"case_id")' alt="Show context menu" />
```

but the second button that is calling the 2nd function is not working - the error "demo1 is not defined"

```
<img src="Img/Menu.png" onclick='demo1.ShowColumnHeaderMenu(event,"case_id")' alt="Show context menu" />
```

Comment: In the first function, you took a variable that was local to that function and exposed it to the global scope by making it a property of window  `var demo = window.demo = {};`  You didn't do that in example2, so your event listener code which runs in global scope has no idea what demo1 is.

Comment: var demo1 = window.demo1= {};  -> I changed it and still same error

Comment: I was able to fixed the problem by using a Radscriptblock controller (per function) that will separate the two functions.